# What would happen to the Subtropical Ridge/Horse latitudes and Polar front if the Earth was rotating 5% faster?

Tags: atmosphere, wind, atmosphere-modelling, earth-rotation

Would they move towards the Equator/Poles? Stay in the same place?

What about if the Earth was rotating 10% slower?

Is there a rotation speed for Earth which will lead to 4 wind belts instead of 3 ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you will find this question informative: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/992/what-factors-determine-the-number-of-hadley-cells-for-a-planet

Comment: @CamiloRada Thanks! But that answer raises more questions. For example your comment is unanswered. Also what are the values of Ω and Θ0 for Earth?

Comment: Why 5% in particular?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest another one of those world building questions - what if ?

Comment: @gansub Is there a rule against it?

Comment: @SidDatta - You need to check on meta

Comment: @SidDatta I don't see any reason why there would be, just wasn't sure if something particular inspired the specific number.  I might have just put "a bit faster" and "a bit slower" rather than 5% and 10%?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I chose small numbers because I already know at big numbers, the climate changes radically. Eg at 200% rotation Earth's wind patterns will be very stormy and might make life impossible. For example, whenever people try to discuss Earth with a higher axial tilt (say 45deg), the discussion veers to 90deg tilted planets (whose weathers are extreme and inhospitable). Extreme situations are not that interesting for Worldbuilding.

Comment: @SidDatta Sounds interesting... certainly haven't pondered those extreme cases much myself, and certainly didn't know of deeper investigation into such... and probably true of most Earth Scientists... could add a link to your question if you happen to have one handy :)

Comment: @SidDatta https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/should-we-host-questions-about-hypothetical-or-fictional-planets/1521#1521

Comment: @gansub I see. I will try to limit my WB questions to the WB stack exchange in that case.