# Why does the Earth have six atmospheric bands?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere

I know that the earth has atmospheric banding like the gas giants.

What I want to know is why six in specific? What physical processes or equations determine the number of atmospheric bands on a planet with an atmosphere?

Also I'm not sure if the intertropical convergence zone counts as a 'band'. If it does the same question holds for why we have seven bands.

NOTES:

This is a follow up to

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163805/why-doesnt-earths-atmosphere-form-bands-due-to-different-rotational-speeds

And has been reposted due to comment request from here

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400417/why-does-the-earth-have-six-atmospheric-bands?noredirect=1#comment897797_400417

Comment: Was already answered a while ago... https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/992/what-factors-determine-the-number-of-hadley-cells-for-a-planet/1004#1004