# Why does cloud cover seem to "ride" a wave that propagates westward near the equator in this video?

Tags: meteorology, climatology, atmospheric-circulation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVRbeGc_6zM

Notice that the cloud cover over Africa and South America is correlated in a way that seems to be highlighting some kind of large-scale easterly wave propagation near the ITCZ? I do not think that the commentary in the video addresses this.

What other wave dynamics should be obvious to my eye, here? The wavenumber ~4 pattern near ±50° are Rossby waves, correct?

Anyone know of a video similar to this that has commentary on the larger-scale dynamics (waves, general circulation), rather than weather?

Comment: I think you may need to capture at least a picture or two to try to show what feature/timing/etc you're talking about?

Comment: Related, but not duplicates (at least I don't think they're duplicates): [What factors determine the number of Hadley cells for a planet?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/992) and [Can we see the circulation cells in wind maps?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18121)

Comment: I see diurnal heating going westward (about once per second).